# Method for storing a large amount of units, with a large array of attributes

Tags: java, database-design, game-engine

Me and a friend are currently looking at developing a game, with similarities to a certain trademarked francise. To define the units in the game, we've created an abstract class which denotes the 44 variables, and two methods that need to be instantiated with each instance of a unit. The next step in this game would be to of course, define all the units in the game. Unfortunately, I have 648 units that need to be defined, with 22 final values for each which must be examined at each individual instantiation in the game. For example, if I encounter this unit in the game, I would pass a method it's value, and it would look at some sort of defining table which give all these base, final values. The problem we've encountered with this of course, is finding a method of doing this effectively, and securely. Currently, for testing of other methods, I have a few units defined through enumeration, and have their values stored in an array. My partner has suggest we create a defining class, which will look at a plaintext lookup table. However, I see the problem with such a solution would either be the length, or quantity of lookup tables would be massive. I have searched around, but most solutions entail the use of a server. Our current goal, however is to just release an offline client with everything already defined.

Anyways, I know this was a lot of possible rambling, but... does anyone have any suggestions on how to store 648 units with 22 different final attributes effectively, so that such an entity could be called later and examined? I don't need a thorough code example, but ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Please write your problem short and presice hence it can be understood.

Comment: I thought I'd done that. The top bit is mostly explanation of what's going on, the second paragraph is a summation... Again, I need an idea for defining and storing a large amount of units, with 22 predetermined values each...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a **database** which contains a **table** of units and a set of **columns** (or fields) for the respective attributes. This is most abstract example I can provide.

An implementation without a server would instead entail a **flat file database** such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Of course, if you want to build your own custom database as your friend suggests, it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Excel or Spreadsheet in Google Documents. Write your table and then export as CSV (comma separated values). Will be very simple to create, modify and parse.